# Adjust image size to fill screen without JS

Tags: html, css

When a user loads the page, I want an image to fill the entire screen. What I want is very similar to `background-size:cover`, but I want to be able to scroll down without the static background.

This is what I have so far:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#bg img {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

The only problem with this, is that the image height is not restricted to the height of the browser window. `height` or `max-height` does not make any difference.

Is there any simple way of achieving this in pure CSS?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem correctly, but have you tried using `100vh` for height and `100vw` for width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`vh` and `vw` Viewport-Relative Length](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) units.

```css
#bg img {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;     /* If you want it to be full width as well as height. */
}
```